# Publish as npm library to github with source code but on install should get the files present in dist

Tags: angular, reactjs, github, npm, ng-packagr

I want to push the code to git hub along with the dist folder but on entering the command `npm i <github-url>` I should get the files to node_modules present inside the dist.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an orphan branch in your repo and only push your `dist` folder with `package.json` there.

Then you can point NPM to install dependency from that branch

```
npm install username/repo#branchName --save
```